# What are some alternatives to Compton and Compiz in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, compton

I have some serious tearing problems and I dont like Compton. And compiz is too heavy. Is there any WM alternatives?

Comment: Tearing problem is usually solved by installing the appropriate and supported graphic driver (usually proprietary). Compositing manager is just a workaround to alleviate the tearing problem, which may *not* work.

Comment: Xfce 4.14 has better compositor

Answer (score 0):

If your just looking for composting, try xcompmgr. It's not a window manager though.

Comment: Isn't `Compton` the successor to `xcompmgr` which is no longer being developed?

Comment: Nope,  not really, Compton is a fork (there are others) but xcompmgr is still being maintained (as of 2015-10-22 at quick glance). It's light weight and more of a proof of concept, so there's not a lot of dev work going to it, but if your wanting a lightweight compositor, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Does it fix any tearing problems?

Comment: You will have to try and see, but usually tearing problems are not directly the compositors fault, but instead the drivers or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Picom**

> This is forked from the original Compton because it seems to have
>   become unmaintained.
>
> The current battle plan of this fork is to refactor it to make the
>   code possible to maintain, so potential contributors won't be scared
>   away when they take a look at the code.
>
> We also try to fix bugs.

https://github.com/yshui/picom